# Calculus 1 - Prove or disprove

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x): [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function.
Given: $f(a)=0$, $f_+'(a)=0$ and f is positive at $(a,b)$ Prove or disprove: there exists $\delta$ such that $\forall x \in (a,a+\delta), f(x) \leq f'(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $a=0,b=1$ and $f(x)=x^{2}\sin (\frac 1  x)$ for $x >0$, $f(0)=0$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied. If the conclusion holds then  $x^{2}\sin (\frac 1  x) \leq 2x\sin (\frac 1  x)-\cos (\frac 1  x)$ for $0<x<\delta$. Take $x=\frac  1 {2n\pi}$ with $n$ sufficiently large to get a contradiction.

[ Note that $x^{2}\sin (\frac 1  x)$ and $2x\sin (\frac 1  x)$ both tend to $0$ as $ x \to 0$ whereas $\cos (2n\pi)=1$ ].

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer!
f is not positive at $(a,b)$ and the derivative doesn't tend to $0$ as $x \to 0$ but oscillates between $-1$ and $1$